# Trying to map over passed array of objects property in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Started learning React and JS not too long ago.
I have a parent class 'App' that gets a an array of objects 'data' from data.js. App.js is sending that 'data' property down to the 'BookList' class. I am trying to map over said property in the BookList class and save elements in 'mappedBooks' but keep getting this error:
TypeError: this.props.books.map is not a function

DATA.JS:

```
    const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: `The Pragmatic Programmer`, 
        author: `David Thomas, Andrew Hunt`,
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51cUVaBWZzL._SX380_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: `HTML and CSS: Design and Build Websites`, 
        author: `Jon Duckett`,
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31aX81I6vnL._SX351_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: `Coding All-in-one For Dummies`, 
        author: `Nikhil Abraham`,
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51RXaV0MGzL._SX397_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: `Learning React`, 
        author: `Alex Banks, Eve Porcello`,
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51FHuacxYjL._SX379_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: `Learning Web Design`, 
        author: `Jennifer Robbins`,
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51iVcZUGuoL._SX408_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        title: `JavaScript and JQuery: Interactive Front-End Web Development`, 
        author: `Jon Duckett`,
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41y31M-zcgL._SX400_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        title: `Head First JavaScript Programming`, 
        author: `Eric Freeman, Elisabeth Robson`,
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qQTSKL2nL._SX430_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        title: `Learning Redux`, 
        author: `Daniel Bugl`,
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41gxBZ8GNpL._SX403_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        title: `Node.js 8 the Right Way`, 
        author: `Jim Wilson`,
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51t44mzlCaL._SX415_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        title: `PostgreSQL: Up and Running`, 
        author: `Regina Obe`,
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51FSjiYDfpL._SX379_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        title: `Fundamentals of Web Development`,
        author: `Randy Connolly, Ricardo Hoar`, 
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xEzGTH6lL._SX402_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        title: `Web Design Playground`,
        author: `Paul McFedries`, 
        img: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41-6F+RDbIL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg`
  }
]
export default data;
```

APP.JS

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import BookList from './Components/BookList';
import Header from './Components/Header'
import Shelf from './Components/Shelf';
import data from './data'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super()

    this.state ={
      books : {data}
    }
    
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <BookList books={this.state.books}/>
      <Shelf/>      
      
    </div>
  );
  }
}
  
export default App;
```

and BOOKLIST.JS:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class BookList extends Component{

    render(){
      
        let mappedBooks = this.props.books.map(function(element){
         return {element}
         })
    
        return(
            <div className = 'BookList'>
                <h1>list</h1>
            </div>
        )
        
    }

}
export default BookList
```

Comment: It should be `this.state = { books: data }` instead of `this.state = { books: {data} }`

Comment: It worked! What do the curly brackets change exactly? When do I use them?

Comment: They are used, in this case, when creating an object with the form `{ key: value }`, i.e.: `{ id: 1 }`, but you tryed to do straight `{ value }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Data.js you've got

```
export default data;
```

and `data` is an array. So when you import data in `App.js` it's an array.

Try running this code snippet to get a better idea of what's going on here:

```js
let data = [1,2,3,4]
console.log('when data is an array')
console.log('{data} is', {data})

data = {
  'data': [1,2,3,4]
}
console.log('when data is an object with a property called data pointing to an array')
console.log('{data} is', {data})

console.log('but if you call a function and pass in data (as an object with data as a named property pointing to an array), you can use the curly braces to pull the array out of the object using destructuring')

function destructureData({data}) {
  console.log(data)
}

destructureData(data)
```

So, when you do this:

```js
this.state = {
  books: { data }
}
```

it's actually an [object property shorthand](https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/) that's interpreted (in ES6) as this:

```js
this.state = {
  books: { data: data }
}
```

If you actually want `this.state.books` to be the array you imported from `data.js` then you set it directly:

```js
this.state = {
  books: data 
}
```

Or, using that object property shorthand, and the fact that you've got data as a default export, you could change the import to this:

```js
import books from './data'
```

And then do this:

```js
this.state = {
  books 
}
```

If you'd like to read more about the destructuring syntax–where you use curly braces to pull data out of an object or an array–[this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is a good read.

Comment: Thank you! It all makes sense now.

Comment: you're welcome! :) Feel free to accept this answer if it was helpful! :-D